# Scrolling EditText inside ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a nasty problem. I have `EditText`(8 lines) inside `ScrollView`. And when I'm trying to scroll text in `EditText` it's behavior is not stable. Sometimes it's scrolling, some times it's not taking focus.

This is my layout file, to make my question more clear:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wo_task_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wo_task_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wo_task_comments_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/comments" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wo_task_select_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_comment_from_template" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/wo_task_comments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_comment_here"
        android:lines="8"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I understand that I'm having this issue because of holding one scrollable control inside another, yet I don't know what to do with this. So, please help me if you can.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void initComments(final View view) {
    EditText comment = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.wo_task_comments);

    comment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.wo_task_comments) {
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
                            false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    comment.setText(currentTask.getComment() + "very very long comment"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment");
}
```

I've tried this, and no result. I'm still unable to scroll my editbox.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .....  
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wo_task_comments);
    et.setOnTouchListener(this);
    .....
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.wo_task_comments){
        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your case:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initComments(findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT_ID));  
}


public void initComments(final View view) {
    EditText comment = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.wo_task_comments);

    comment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.wo_task_comments) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
                                false);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    comment.setText("very very long comment"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment\n" + "very very long comment\n"
            + "very very long comment");
}
```

}

Comment: Was just posting the same answer, as an addition you maybe have to disable other scrolling 

otherviews.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
   }
  });

Comment: thanks for response. For the moment I'm still unable to fix my problem.

Comment: Yes, I was just to post that it was my mistake. Well, shit happens, I hate such mistakes:) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Shilkin's code works great.I make it a little more stronger.Now it handle the situation that the EditText's direct parent is not the ScrollView(eg, EditText is wrapped in LinearLayout before it put into the scrollview).

The method code:

```
public static void handleEditTextScrollable(EditText editText, final int resId) {
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (v.getId() == resId) {
                ViewParent parent = v.getParent();
                while (!(parent instanceof ScrollView)) {
                    parent = parent.getParent();
                }
                parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
handleEditTextScrollable(comment, R.id.wo_task_comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

One Option is to set the height of the child `EditText` as the height of the total max lines (max_lines * font_height). So, the internal scroll will be off and the only scroll will be the parent scroll.