# How to scroll within a textbox when the parent screen also needs to be scrolled

Tags: android

I have an activity screen which is having more contents than can fit on device screen, so that activity screen has a scrolling functionality.

In the activity screen, one of the controls is a textview. Its a multi line textview, however, if the user types more text than can fit in the TextView and he wants to scroll within the textview, then the scrolling gesture actually scrolls the screen instead of scrolling the TextView.

Is there any elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770252/scrolling-editbox-inside-scrollview/9770373#9770373

Comment: Sorry, its an EditText not a TextView.

Comment: It doesn't metter. In xml add for your TextView: android:scrollbars = "vertical" and android:maxLines="5". In activity: yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); And use the link I gave above

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one widget scrolling on the same axis.

Since you have a ScrollView in your Activity, set the TextView's layout_height to be "wrap_content".