# How to stop ExpandableListView from stealing child touch events?

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager in a group view (section header) of an ExpandableListView. As expected, scrolling of ViewPager sometimes becomes choppy, most probably because the ExpandableListView is trying to intercept the touch events. As a solution, I am trying to prevent the ExpandableListView from intercepting touch events if they are meant for the ViewPager. So, far, this is what i have done.

```
private void fixViewPager(ViewPager vp) {
    vp.setOnTouchListener(new ViewPager.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                Logger.log("Disabling event stealing");
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                Logger.log("Enabling event stealing");
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });     
}
```

But, the touch listener never gets the ACTION_DOWN event. It only seems to get the ACTION_UP event. What can i do to solve my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Shortly after I posted my question, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9770373/1036017. Based on that I changed my code to the following. Now, the ViewPager prevents the ExpandableListView from stealing touch events, once horizontal scrolling starts within the ViewPager.

```
private void fixViewPager(ViewPager vp) {
    vp.setOnTouchListener(new ViewPager.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Logger.log("Disabling event stealing.");
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to properly use the method **requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()** in viewPager. Use the following custom viewpager class:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
 boolean xScored = false, yScored = false;

 public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

 public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        xScored = false;
        yScored = false;
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
 }

  GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (!yScored && Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)) {
            xScored = true;
            yScored = false;
        }
        if (xScored) {
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        } else if (!xScored && Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
            xScored = false;
            yScored = true;
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        return true;
     }

  };
  GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGestureListener);
 }
```